# Minor Active Admin issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activeadmin

Im building a membership web application with Ruby on Rails. I set up my DB and relationships between tables, everything worked fine. I decided to use Active Admin to shortcut the creation of a dashboard as well as providing a good search feature.

The issue I'm currently having is in Active admin on my dropdown list and table the foreign keys are only showing Id numbers and reference addresses (sorry, I forgot what their actually called).

[Pics of my issue:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPxJb.png)

How can go about fixing this and in which files.
I would greatly Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customize ActiveAdmin Index Filters > [Change The String Representation](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/customize-activeadmin-index-filters#change-the-string-representation)

Above article explains the similar issue. you have to do something like this in admin page for membership.

```
  filter :plan, collection: -> {
    Plan.all.map { |plan| [plan.name, plan.id] }
  }
```

I have used `name` attribute for plan as an example. you may have different attribute, use correct attribute to reflect the details.

**Update**

Based on @DevOps92 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64150251/2788206)

Alternate way to achieve this is to set any the method `:display_name, :full_name, :name, :title, :to_s` in `Plan` model

[Active Admin Doc](https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html#defining-columns)

> For association columns we make an educated guess on what to display by calling the following methods in the following order:
>
> :display_name, :full_name, :name, :username, :login, :title, :email, :to_s
>
> This can be customized in config/initializers/active_admin.rb.

Comment: Thank you for you input, but this was not the solution to my issue. I solved the issue by adding display_name method in my rails model for plan and membership

Comment: That seems to be proper fix. feel free to mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks @DevOps92 I have updated my answer to include your answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by going to my models that was generated by rails when I created the table in my database via scaffold. App/models/plan.rd  and used the method display_name. Within the display_name method I listed the column name from the plan table. so anyone facing a similar issue check your rails models.  ​           ​                                                    ​             ​                                                          ​
[My Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUjDY.png)